# How can PC-Lint be integrated into Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, pc-lint

We have been able to integrated PC-Lint 9.00c into Visual Studio using the description in the [env-vc10.lnt](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pub90/env-vc10.lnt) file. Is there any similar way or description to get PC-lint running from Qt-Creator 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [QtProjectTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtprojecttool/) plugin could do the trick?

Comment: The big problem seems to be that pc-lint don't understand the Qt concepts and macros, giving a lot of false errors. So the plugin might help getting a *.lnt file with the files to lint, but it will not be an fully woring integration as the one in visual studio.

Comment: Ok, the question confused me, since the question is tagged with "qt-creator", but is really a question about Qt as such. To create such a .lnt file, these posts can help as clues, then one needs to turn off each warning using "-emacro": [link](http://www.gimpel.com/Discussion.cfm?ThreadID=2398) [link](http://www.gimpel.com/Discussion.cfm?ThreadID=4004). Hope that gets you started.